# From a text file to a Dictionary in SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary

I am new to databases and programming so bear with me.

I am trying to store textfiles into a database. These textfiles are black, white and grey lists wich contain a few words. Whenever someone notices a word that should be in the black list, it should be simply added in the database.

So I have these words that need to be in a dictionary but how do I do that and then store them to a database? When that's done how do I retrieve these words from the database? Do I just make a table or make a dictionary first? I am really confused as for how I should start making this.

Thank you for your time, any tutorials are very welcome.

Comment: The WROX book on Database design is very good.

Comment: @TabAlleman Looks good thanks!

Comment: You need to learn the following : FileStreams(StreamReader) for reading/writing from/to your files in disk, DataStructures returned by FileStreams, DataSets, ADO.Net/Entity Framework to read/write data from/to databases.

Comment: Split your task into smaller separate ones like: 1. get words from textfile into some C# collection (list or dictionary - it doesn't matter right now). 2. Create table(s) in some database to store these words. 3. Learn how to establish database connection from c# application and make data manipulation. When you face some concrete problem - come back to StackOverflow and ask concrete question. Right now your question is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: Why do you want to store them in a dictionary? You could store them in 3 different tables, in a SQL database, called "Blacklist", "Greylist" and "Whitelist". This way you can easily add word to any of the three tables or check whether a word exists in the tables. If you need more on how to use SQL, check out [W3C schools - SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)